Iterate through the ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator list using c++/JNI in Android
I am fairly new with cpp or jni in android. I have few lines of code in kotlin which I want to move it to cpp, reason being want to make the validation in bit more secure way.
Kotlin code:
val entries = ZipFile(context.packageCodePath).entries().toList()
var totalCrc = 0L
for (entry in entries) {
   if (entry.name.startsWith(DEX_FILENAME)) totalCrc += entry.crc
}

What I could achieve in cpp:
jclass zipFileClass = env->FindClass("java/util/zip/ZipFile");
    jmethodID zipFileConstructor = env->GetMethodID(zipFileClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jobject zipFileObject = env->NewObject(zipFileClass, zipFileConstructor, packageCodePath);
    jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(zipFileClass, "entries", "()Ljava/util/Enumeration;");
    jobject zipFileList = env->CallObjectMethod(zipFileObject, methodId);

    jclass ZipEntryIteratorClass = env->FindClass("java/util/zip/ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator");

**    // This line doesnt have any error from the compiler. **
    jmethodID mid_Iterator_hasNext = env->GetMethodID(ZipEntryIteratorClass, "hasMoreElements", "()Z");
     
**    // I get error at this line, for some reason jni layer is not able to find the nextElement method**
    jmethodID mid_Iterator_next = env->GetMethodID(ZipEntryIteratorClass, "nextElement", "()Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;");
**    // This line also is able to run without any exception. **
    jboolean hasMoreElements = env->CallBooleanMethod(zipFileList, mid_Iterator_hasNext);

**// Of course below code doesnt work, due to the exception**

    //jobject v = env->CallObjectMethod(zipFileList, mid_Iterator_next);
    //env->DeleteLocalRef(v);

**// This is the logic which I would eventually have to iterate through the items.**
    //while (hasMoreElements) {
        //jobject v = env->CallObjectMethod(zipFileList, mid_Iterator_next);
        // Do something with `v`

        // Avoid overflowing the local reference table if legList gets large
        //env->DeleteLocalRef(v);
    //}

The exception I get is:
runtime.cc:677] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallBooleanMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/util/zip/ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator;.nextElement()Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;"
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at boolean com.something.else.RandomScreenActivity.validateChecksum(java.lang.String) (RandomScreenActivity.kt:-2)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void com.something.else.RandomScreenActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (RandomScreenActivity.kt:72)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:8051)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:8031)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1329)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3608)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3792)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:2210)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at boolean android.os.Looper.loopOnce(android.os.Looper, long, int) (Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7839)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677] 
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]     in call to CallBooleanMethodV
                                                                                                    runtime.cc:677]     from boolean RandomScreenActivity.validateChecksum(java.lang.String)

Additionally ZipEntryIterator class from the java.util.ZipFIle class has following methods which can be used to iterate through the items:
private class ZipEntryIterator implements Enumeration<ZipEntry>, Iterator<ZipEntry> {
        private int i = 0;

        public ZipEntryIterator() {
            ensureOpen();
        }

        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
            return hasNext();
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            synchronized (ZipFile.this) {
                ensureOpen();
                return i < total;
            }
        }

        public ZipEntry nextElement() {
            return next();
        }

        public ZipEntry next() {
            synchronized (ZipFile.this) {
                ensureOpen();
                if (i >= total) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                long jzentry = getNextEntry(jzfile, i++);
                if (jzentry == 0) {
                    String message;
                    if (closeRequested) {
                        message = "ZipFile concurrently closed";
                    } else {
                        message = getZipMessage(ZipFile.this.jzfile);
                    }
                    throw new ZipError("jzentry == 0" +
                                       ",\n jzfile = " + ZipFile.this.jzfile +
                                       ",\n total = " + ZipFile.this.total +
                                       ",\n name = " + ZipFile.this.name +
                                       ",\n i = " + i +
                                       ",\n message = " + message
                        );
                }
                ZipEntry ze = getZipEntry(null, jzentry);
                freeEntry(jzfile, jzentry);
                return ze;
            }
        }
    }

Any suggestion how to iterate through the ZipEntryIterator list?

You forgot the semicolon at the end of your signature for nextElement. Should be "()Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;" Don't write them yourself, copy-paste them from javap -s output.

I don't see how any of this will make "validation a bit more secure", but okay.

Yes the whole topic of "Secure" is debatable. Thanks for the quick suggestion, added the semicolon. Still I am getting the error. Have updated the question.
Also I am suing Android Studio for the development, I am not sure if I can run the javap -s command from terminal, could give a try though
Error:
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallBooleanMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/util/zip/ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator;.nextElement()Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;"

On my virtual Android device, I get the following logcat entry:

Accessing hidden method Ljava/util/zip/ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator;nextElement()Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry; (max-target-r, JNI, denied)

I also found this line in the Android codebase, which confirms the warning message above.
which makes me think you should stick to the generic Enumeration interface.
The ZipFile class returns a generic Enumeration interface, which only returns Objects. So:
jmethodID mid_Iterator_next = env->GetMethodID(ZipEntryIteratorClass, "nextElement", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");


Thanks for the suggestion. I will give a try. I am using ZipEntryIterator since the compiler complained that the return type is ZipEntryIterator. I can still give  a try and iterate over it.

Documentation just says it's an Enumeration of ZipEntry objects

Agree 100%, I dropped the ZipEntryIterator and used Enumerator interface instead and was able to iterate through the list. As suggested the nextElement return type was Object and eventually used the ZipEntry properties with the object and was finally able to finish. Cant thanks you much, I was struggling with this topic since a week, this really helped me. Thanks again. For some reason I am not able to upvote due to reputation points.
